# How to solve this simple problem in retopology?

Tags: modeling, retopology

What should I do in such cases? I tried adding more detail on the fold of the frog's paw and now I dont able to connect this quads:
[image]

Comment: This link has some good tips for edge loop reducion: https://topologyguides.com/loop-reduction

Answer (score 5):

You could use this kind of topology but it means deleting one edge, it seems to work fine with your current topology though:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the vertices...

[image]

and choose Face -> Grid fill

[image]

and you will get:

[image]

Comment: I think his question is more about how could I reduce my topology?

Comment: @moonboots: Ahhh …the blue area…now…yep, i think you are right! 